How does information traverse through a neural network such as LSTMs or ESNs?
In "The “echo state” approach to analysing and training recurrent neural networks-with an erratum note" (2001), H. Jaeger defines the "Echo State Network" (ESN). I have read that ESNs are a type of RNN, a way to train RNNs, and an instance of Reservoir Computing.
One of the stark differences between ESN and the more traditional RNN is the dynamical reservoir (see figure below from Jaeger (2001)). As far as I understand, the reservoir is an RNN itself, but it doesn't have the well-known structure of chained-up (hidden) layers. Instead, all the hidden layers are substituted by a single layer where nodes have all-to-all nonlinear connections.
Mathematically, Jaeger (2001) defines
$$
x(n+1) = f\Big({W^{in}} u(n+1) + {W^{}} x(n) + {W^{back}} y(n)\Big) \\
{y}(n+1) = {f^{out}}\Big({W^{out}} (u(n+1),x(n+1),y(n) \Big)
$$
where $n$ is the time step,  $u(n) \in \mathbb{R}^K, x(n) \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $y(n) \in \mathbb{R}^L$ are, respectively, the input, the internal, and the output states. The matrices are $W^{in} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}, W \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}, W^{back} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times L}$, and $W^{out} \in \mathbb{R}^{L × (K + N + L)}$.
Jaeger (2001) says "The activation of internal units is updated according to" the first equation and "The output is computed according to" the second equation.
How does the information from an input vector $u$ travel "through" the internal reservoir until it is outputted?
My question comes from conflating the length of vector $u$ and the time step $n$. If my input is a time series vector of length $i = 1, ..., K$, then every time step $i$ relates to a different time-indexed element in $u \in \mathbb{R}^K$. But given how $u$ is defined, it seems that $u(n)$ always has length $K$, and as $n$ changes, the values in $u(n)$ are transformed. Here, I assume the transformation happens through the activation1 of the neurons. If I have a time-series vector $u = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and feed it my ESN to get an output (likely, a forecast of pre-defined length), how many times steps will that take?
Initially, I thought my problem was in understanding how information passes through something that is "amorphous" as a dynamical reservoir. But pondering on it, I now see the gap in my knowledge also apply to more traditional RNNs, such as LSTMs. For instance, if I have a vector of length 100 and an LSTM with 3 hidden layers with 10 nodes (or neurons) in each layer, does the first-time step take in only 10 elements from the 100-element vector? Then does the second time step take 10 more elements? So, does the LSTM need 100 time steps to process the 100-element vector and produce an output?


1 I use the word "activation" to mean the output of a node after an activation function is applied to it. If the result is not zero, I say the node is activated and it passes information forward. I take it this concept is widely understood by the community, but since I'm not in AI "proper", I thought I'd state it.

the input is propagated to every neuron, which updates its state, and the output is then computed from this new neurons state
